# SQLite жизнь в андроиде

Tags: android, android-sqlite

При удалении приложения, удаляется и `SharedPreferences` файл, а если использовать `SQLite` (без `ContentProvider`, то есть чистый без подключения к внешним базам по апи, например), удалить приложение и заново установить?

Насколько я понимаю, то он поведет себя так же, как и в случае `SharedPreferences`, ведь по сути бд хранится в папке точно так же, во внутренней директории с исходниками программы.

Так вот вопрос состоит в том, какой лайфсайкл у `SQLite` в андроиде, каким образом можно содержать данные даже после переустановки программы?

Где я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

База тоже вайпается, как и sharedPreferences, лайфсайкл совпадает. Данные лучше хранить на сервере куда пользователь не имеет доступа.

Answer (score 3):

Локальная БД действительно хороша, когда следует сохранить данные пользователя на время жизни самого приложения. При удалении приложения она естественно тоже удаляется. Но при обновлении приложения она остается, так же как и все сохраненные в нее данные. Более того есть механизмы обновления существующей БД с сохранением данных даже, если меняется ее структура. Использовать для хранения данных sharedPreferences, локальную БД либо БД на сервере это зависит от задач, которые решаются в данном приложении.